# What do different bracket optional argument notations mean on MDN

Tags: javascript

This is very trivial, but I like to know why things are the way they are. 
I'm doing my best at writing js documentation for my apps and so I am using the jsDoc conventions and referring to MDN as a guide and bla bla bla but my question regards how the documentation is written on the MDN reference.

Take two simple methods:
`console.log()` and `Math.min()` and their syntax documented on MDN

```
console.log(obj1 [, obj2, ..., objN]);
console.log(msg [, subst1, ..., substN]);

Math.min([value1[, value2[, ...]]])
```

If I understand correctly `console.log` says, I require the first argument and the rest are optional. The optional arguments are indicated with a bracket + comma "`[,`" whereas a required argument would be indicated with just a comma "`,`".

In addition, to refer to many arguments, the documentation is written as, "`subst1, ..., substN`".

Looking at `Math.min` this is very similar and obviously different, but why? I understand the first arg in `Math.min` is optional (returns `Infinity`) and in console.log it is not optional (you would get `undefined`). If I understand the syntax correctly the syntax for `Math.min` could be written as,

```
Math.min([value1, ..., valueN])
```

stating that ALL arguments are optional and that the method accepts zero or many arguments, but instead we get brackets around every argument.

Is there a reason for the difference in how the documentation is written and if so please explain what that difference is.

Comment: I think the answer is no more profound than *different authors unfortunately applied different conventions.*

Comment: What if optional arguments require other arguments?

Comment: @MinusFour, Array.prototype.map illustrates arguments that contain additional properties, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: That wasn't really my point. There's a difference between `fn(arg [, arg2, arg3])` and `fn(arg1 [, arg2 [, arg3]])`. On the first one arg3 is required if you used arg2 while on the other arg3 isn't required. Well, that's the meaning I make of it (I don't think there's a strict notation for this?)

Comment: _"If I understand the syntax correctly the syntax for Math.min could be written as,

_"Math.min([value1, ..., valueN]) 
stating that ALL arguments are optional and that the method accepts zero or many arguments, but instead we get brackets around every argument."_ At `Math.min` would perhaps expect at least _two_ parameters passed to compare values and return the minimum number value; if only one parameter passed , that would be the minimum number value returned

Comment: @guest271314 would, but in Javascript you can use `Function.prototype.apply` to dispatch an array of arguments to a function. In that case it's way more convenient to have no limits on argument count. So even if you have no values, `Math.min.apply(Math, yourArray)` does not throw error.

Comment: whelp, from what I am understanding here, @deceze, provided the answer that makes the most sense. I like the discussion going on though. Definitely brings up more considerations.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I was always convinced that syntax `fn(a, [b, c, d])` means that you can only use either `fn(a)` or `fn(a, b, c, d)`.

But anyway, `console.log` and `Math.min` behave exactly the same way - they process all the arguments. There is no error if you provide zero arguments to either function. This is what I get in the console:

```
> Math.min()
Infinity
> console.log()
(nothing to output)
```

Also, return value of `console.log` is independent on the parameters - always `undefined`:

```
console.log()==console.log(666) //true
```

Comment: Yes, `[b, c, d]` *would* mean that there are three-or-nothing optional arguments, but `[b1, …, bN]` is different - it means an arbitrary (`N`) amount of optional arguments.