# Javascript Age verification fails on different Browsers

Tags: javascript

We have a weird situation where our javascript fails on specific browser.

Before we had a similar problem with Firefox, now we've got an error for Safari/iOS-browsers. Based on my further experiences most likely the `age` is **`NaN`**. As iPads browsers doesn't have any sort of console I cant validate that.

HTML Markup:

```
<div class="field">
            <label for="billing:month" class="required">Geburtstag *</label>
<div class="onestepcheckout-error customer-dob-error"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Sie müssen mindestens 18 Jahre alt sein, um bei diesem Kunden zu bestellen.</div>
<div class="input-box customer-dob">
    <div class="dob-day">
             <input type="text" data-selector="d" id="billing:day" name="billing[day]" value="" title="Tag" class="input-text validate-custom">
             <label for="billing:day">TT</label>
         </div><div class="dob-month">
             <input type="text" data-selector="m" id="billing:month" name="billing[month]" value="" title="Monat" class="input-text validate-custom">
             <label for="billing:month">MM</label>
         </div><div class="dob-year">
             <input type="text" data-selector="y" id="billing:year" name="billing[year]" value="" title="Jahr" class="input-text validate-custom" autocomplete="off">
             <label for="billing:year">JJJJ</label>
         </div>    
    <div class="dob-full" style="display:none;">
        <input type="hidden" id="billing:dob" name="billing[dob]">
    </div>

    <div class="validation-advice" style="display:none;"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

The Javascript:

```
//<![CDATA[
    var customer_dob = new Varien.DOB('.customer-dob', true, '%d.%m.%Y');

    jQuery(window).load(function($){ 
        var sPath = window.location.pathname;

        // OPTION 1: /customer/account/create/
        // OPTION 2: /onestepcheckout/
        // OPTION 3: /customer/account/edit/

        ////console.log(sPath);

        var age = [];

        if(sPath == "/onestepcheckout/"){
            var disButID = "#onestepcheckout-place-order";
        } else if (sPath == "/customer/account/create/") {
            var disButID = ".buttons-set button.button";
        } else if (sPath == "/customer/account/edit/") {
            var disButID = ".buttons-set button.button";
        }

        ////console.log(disButID);

        //jQuery(disButID).prop("disabled", true);

        jQuery(".customer-dob input").each(function($){
            var entity = jQuery(this).attr("name");
            ////console.log(entity);
            if(entity == "day" || entity == "month" || entity == "year"){
                var selector = jQuery(this).attr("data-selector");
                age[selector] = parseInt(jQuery(this).val(), 10);
                getAge(age);
                //console.log("Change check: " + age);
            } else if (entity == "dob") {
                // ... 
            }
        });

        jQuery(".customer-dob input").change(function($){
            var selector = jQuery(this).attr("data-selector");
            age[selector] = jQuery(this).val();
            getAge(age);
        });

        function getAge(age) {
            if(age["d"] && age["m"] && age["y"]){
                var day = age["d"],
                month = age["m"],
                year = age["y"];

                //console.log("Date: " + day, month, year);     
                unlockOrderButton(day, month, year);
            }
        }

        function unlockOrderButton(day, month, year){

            //var dateString = month + "-" + day + "-" + year;
            var dateString = year + ", " + month + ", " + day; 
            //console.log("Date String in unlockOrderButton: " + dateString);
            var today = new Date();
            var birthDate = new Date(dateString);
            //console.log("Birthdate: " + birthDate);
            var currentAge = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
            var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();

            if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) {
                currentAge--;
            } else {
                currentAge;
            }

            ////console.log("Unlock Button - Check - " + currentAge);
            if(parseInt(currentAge) >= 18){
                jQuery(".customer-dob-error").removeClass("active");
                jQuery(disButID).prop("disabled", false);
                //console.log("Unlock Button - Success. Age is: " + parseInt(currentAge, 10));
            } else {
                jQuery(".customer-dob-error").addClass("active");
                jQuery(disButID).prop("disabled", true);
                console.debug("Unlock Button - Fail. Age is: " + parseInt(currentAge, 10));
            }
        }
    });
    //]]>
```

This code works in the following browsers:

- Chrome 55 and above
- Firefox 50 and above
- IE 11 and above

This code works **not** on the following devices:

- iPad Safari
- iOS Safari

Why and how could I make it work? Last time, the `date()` function was malformed and needed to be adjusted, but this time I'm using `date()` in the correct way as specified in the Docs. However, it does not work. Why?

Comment: Define "doesn't work". What is the error?

Comment: Instead of new Date(dateString), try new Date(year, month - 1, day). For month, recall 0 is January, 1 is February, etc (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getmonth.asp)

Comment: My assumption would also be new Date being the issue. Comma delimited values are not a valid input. See [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: Updated question. Marie - if you take a look at MDN you'll see that comma seperated inputs are fine - or am I wrong here? `new Date(year, month[, date[, hours[, minutes[, seconds[, milliseconds]]]]]);`. This really looks like a comma seperated input.

Comment: That looks like a comma separated nested array mess.

Comment: @takendarkk That's the syntax MDN uses to show that the `Date` constructor can take year and month only, or optionally include date, or optionally hours, etc.. You can see that in the text descriptions [on the page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). Comma-separated numerical values are indeed valid input for the Date constructor. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/34791848/215552

Comment: Its funny to see 4 browsers working perfectly fine, but an iPad or an iOS device can't handle that stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was to change one line from

`var dateString = year + ", " + month + ", " + day;`

to

`var dateString = year + "/" + month + "/" + day;`

Weird.